# Ubuntu 13.10 won't wake up after suspend

Tags: 13.10, suspend

I have some difficulties with Ubuntu 13.10 (3.11.0-14-generic) and waking up from suspend state. Screen just goes blank, and there is some kind of prompt blink in upper right corner after I just need to restart my computer.

Specs:

- DE: Gnome
- Intel® Core™ i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- GeForce GTX 650/PCIe/SSE2
- with: NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, nvidia-331 (open source)
- 16 GB of RAM
- (`/` folder on SSD Drive, `/home` on HDD)

P.S.
Nvidia graphic driver works perfectly without any glitches.
Thanks for any help you can provide..

Comment: It may have to do with the power manager. Try in the terminal using Code:
sudo pm-suspend

Comment: @MaciMint: If someone's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the system isn't turning your LCD backlight back on, then you can probably turn it back on manually..

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (go to a text virtual console) and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (go back to the graphical X display)

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> should cause the backlight to come on, and then you can get back to your session with the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

You might need to adjust the screen brightness with function keys on a laptop. This is if it is turning on the backlight but just at the lowest brightness.

There are multiple cases of this, not related to this card directly.

Comment: You need to test if you can ssh or connect to another service after the wake up command is issued.

Comment: But if they see a prompt cursor in the top corner then it is not a backlight problem.

Comment: He need to clarify the state of the machine, whether or not it recovered from suspend (ie. services running etc) to identify if it is a restore state, hardware(driver) or software problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem and was wrestling with it for weeks. If you're still having problems try this: [Disable Apport at Boot](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-disable-apport-error-reporting-in-ubuntu#.UyqRHB8-vng).

You need to manually edit a file to stop Apport running at boot (when you turn on your machine). Open the Terminal, and paste the following command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, or type it in manually:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/apport
```

Change the line that says `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` to disable Apport. To re-enable, change it back.